# Javascript Data Type Condition

Tags: javascript, typeof

Today I found a troll with few condition. But the basic is
"if I pass the exam then I have to arranage a party. But if I fail in the exam then I have to study attentively"

That is a simple if, else condition. But I faced too many problems. I have to mentioned that I am learning JS. So simple problem may seem hard to me.

I made if, else if, else condition for "exam pass or fail". But I was struck, when I enter a value excpet "pass condition".

Note: I tagged "pass" as "good" & "fail" as "bad".

What I faced let me explain :(

1. When I enter except "good" word. Then I need a message to enter "good" or "bad"
2. If I enter any number, then I need a message to enter "good" or "bad"
3. If I submit input field without any value. Then I need a message to enter "good" or "bad" or something else

I made a script in my own hand. But I faced too many unanswered questions.

1. If I enter a input following this pattern "textnumber"
   eg. "good123"
   Then it shows undefined. I don't why :(
   Why "good123" marked as "typeof" "undefined" ????
2. The most myterious thing to me. If I enter "good" it shows correct condition output, but if I enter "Good" then it shows undefined. 
   I want to mean that: If I enter case sensitive word then the input doesn't satisfy the condition. In my example, I solved it in a way. But please look for me, is there any way to solve this issue.

Last of all, I made a script in my own way. There might be any other way to create this project or can  be simplify the script in alternative way. I will be greatful if you suggest me that. Also please suggest me how I overcome the problem I faced. Any alternative way to resolve these noted issue without my way.

Regards
Md Rizaur

```html
<!--The Script Is Made By Md Rizaur Rahman from https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192572/md-rizaur-rahman-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Simple Logic By Md Rizaur Rahman</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function logic() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("logic").value;
    var input = userInput.toLowerCase();
    var onlyStr = /^[a-zA-z]+$/;
    var onlyNum =/^[0-9]+$/;
    var output;
    if(input === "good"){
        output = "Lets Party"
    }
    else if(input === "bad"){
        output = "Please Study Attentively"
    }
    else if ((input.match(onlyStr)) && (input !== "good")){
        output = "You Enter String Without \"Good\" Word. Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    else if(input.match(onlyNum)){
        output = "You Enter A Number. Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    else if (input.trim() == ""){
        output = "Please Enter Any Value or Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    else{
        output = "Your Input Type Is Marked As Undefined. Please Enter Any Value or Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    alert (output);
}


</script>

<input type="text" id="logic">
<button onclick="logic()" type="submit" id="input">Submit</button>
<p id="html_output"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of using regex to check types, use `typeof`

Comment: @Pavitra `typeof` is always going to return `string`

Comment: 1) ""good123" does not match either regex. (It's not "undefined". It just doesn't match any condition) and 2) Works fine on this page.

Comment: @Keith In his code, he tries to check whether the input is a string or a number using regex in 3rd & 4th conditions.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: User can enter any upper case or lower case string in the input field. So I have to make a variable which force the string(s) into lower case using " var input = userInput.toLowerCase();"
Isn't the right way ?

Comment: @Pavitra  There are no numbers here, input is always a string.  so typeof is always going to be string.

Comment: @MDRIZAURRAHMAN Sure, that's fine. But in your question you say "Good" fails but if you run the snippet it seems to work fine.

Comment: @MDRIZAURRAHMAN  What problem are you trying to solve, your current code snippet appears to do everything you require,.. Can you supply some examples of inputs and expected outputs, and flag were wrong.

Comment: Ok, I can understand now @Keith

Comment: @Pavitra, 
How can use typeof instead of regex, for following condition ?

    else if ((input.match(onlyStr)) && (input !== "good")){
        output = "You Enter String Without \"Good\" Word. Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }

Comment: @Pavitra, I figure out the above commented statement can be:
        else if ((typeof input === "string" ) && (input !== "good")){
            output = "You Enter String Without \"Good\" Word. Please Enter Good or Bad";
        }



Ain't I right ?

Answer (score 0):

It is marked as undefined because it does not satisfy any of the conditions above (it does not match the regular expression and is not "good" or "bad"). Change your regular expression to `/^[a-zA-z0-9]+$/` (accepting numbers from 0-9) and put checking for numeric values in front of that `else if`, using `!isNaN(input)`. You should also change the input to lowercase before checking if it equals "good" or "bad". For the `isNaN` check to work correctly, you will also need to check if the `input` is all spaces (`if(!input.trim().length)`) as a space is also treated as a number (is not NaN).

```html
<!--The Script Is Made By Md Rizaur Rahman from https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192572/md-rizaur-rahman-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Simple Logic By Md Rizaur Rahman</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function logic() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("logic").value;
    var input = userInput.toLowerCase();
    var onlyStr = /^[a-zA-z0-9]+$/;
    var onlyNum =/^[0-9]+$/;
    var output;
    if(input.toLowerCase() === "good"){
        output = "Lets Party"
    }
    else if(input.toLowerCase() === "bad"){
        output = "Please Study Attentively"
    } 
    else if(!input.trim().length){
      output = "Input can not be empty!";
    }
    else if(!isNaN(input)){
     output = "You Enter A Number. Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    else if ((input.match(onlyStr)) && (input !== "good")){
        output = "You Enter String Without \"Good\" Word. Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    else if (input.trim() == ""){
        output = "Please Enter Any Value or Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    else{
        output = "Your Input Type Is Marked As Undefined. Please Enter Any Value or Please Enter Good or Bad";
    }
    alert (output);
}


</script>

<input type="text" id="logic">
<button onclick="logic()" type="submit" id="input">Submit</button>
<p id="html_output"></p>

</body>
</html>
```